# on slave machine datanodes are on but it is throwing error with the command "hdfs hdfsadmin -report"?

Tags: hadoop

hduser@master-virtual-machine:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ jps 
5934 Jps
3490 SecondaryNameNode
3678 ResourceManager
5108 NameNode
hduser@master-virtual-machine:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
15/02/28 22:35:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

---

Datanodes available: 0 (0 total, 0 dead)

Comment: configurations is multinode hadoop-2.2.0 on ubuntu-12.04 desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check your datanode logs for any errors, and also see if datanode config files are configured properly ?

Comment: how to check datanode logs and also see if datanode config files are configured properly?

Comment: If you have a tar ball installation, your **HADOOP_HOME/logs** will have logs and **HADOOP_HOME/etc** will have config files. If you have an rpm installation, check **/var/logs/** for logs and **/etc/hadoop/conf** for config files.